# how can I job connect with sink on spring XD?

Tags: java, xml, spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-xd

I want custom job module connected with the custom sink module on spring XD!

also, I want to use **output channel** in the job module. ( so that i may data trasmission) :(

below is my 'batch-module.xml'.

```
<context:annotation-config/>

<context:component-scan base-package="test.server.springxdmodules.job"/>

<util:properties id="config" location="classpath:application.yml"/>

<int:channel id="output"/>

<int:gateway id="gateway"
             service-interface="test.server.springxdmodules.job.gateway.MessageGateway">
    <int:method name="sendMessage" request-channel="output"/>
</int:gateway>

<!-- Actual Job -->
<batch:job id="data-remover-job">
    <batch:step id="query-generation-step">
        <batch:tasklet ref="pastDataRemoveTasklet"/>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="pastDataRemoveTasklet"
      class="test.server.springxdmodules.job.tasklet.PastRemoveDataTasklet"/>
```

below is job launch exception on spring xd.

> **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException**: **Job module doesn't have
>   output channel set.**     at
>   org.springframework.xd.dirt.plugins.AbstractJobPlugin.getOutputChannelName(AbstractJobPlugin.java:49)
>   ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.xd.dirt.plugins.AbstractMessageBusBinderPlugin.bindConsumerAndProducers(AbstractMessageBusBinderPlugin.java:143)
>   ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.xd.dirt.plugins.job.JobPlugin.postProcessModule(JobPlugin.java:65)
>   ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.postProcessModule(ModuleDeployer.java:238)
>   ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.doDeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:218)
>   ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]......

Thanks in advance :).